# OneDrive API Resumable upload url not responding

Tags: c#, file-upload, microsoft-graph-api

I have been developing a OneDrive desktop client app because the one built into windows has been failing me for reasons I cannot figure out.  I'm using the REST API in C# via an `HttpClient`.

All requests to the onedrive endpoint work fine (downloading, uploading small files, etc.) and uploading large files worked fine up until recently (about two days ago).  I get the upload session URL and start uploading data to it, but after uploading two chunks to it successfully (202 response), the third request and beyond times out (via the `HttpClient`), whether it be a `GET` to get the status, or a `PUT` to upload data.  The `POST` to create the session still works.

I have tried: getting a new `ClientId`, logging into a new Microsoft account, reverting code to a known working state, and recloning git repository.

In PostMan, I can go through the whole process of creating a session and uploading chunks and not experience this issue, but if I take an upload URL that my application retrieves from the OneDrive API and try to `PUT` data to it in PostMan, the server doesn't respond (unless the request is invalid, then it sometimes tells me).  Subsequent `GET` requests to this URL also don't respond.

Here is a log of all requests going to the OneDrive API after authentication: https://pastebin.com/qRrw2Sb5

and here is the relevant code:

```
//first, create an upload session
var httpResponse = await _httpClient.StartAuthenticatedRequest(url, HttpMethod.Post).SendAsync(ct);
if (httpResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    return new HttpResult<IRemoteItemHandle>(httpResponse, null);
}


//get the upload URL
var uploadSessionRequestObject = await HttpClientHelper.ReadResponseAsJObjectAsync(httpResponse);

var uploadUrl = (string)uploadSessionRequestObject["uploadUrl"];
if (uploadUrl == null)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Successful OneDrive CreateSession request had invalid body!");
    //TODO: what to do here?
}

//the length of the file total
var length = data.Length;

//setup the headers
var headers = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Content-Length", ""),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Content-Range","")
};

JObject responseJObject;
//the response that will be returned
HttpResponseMessage response = null;

//get the chunks
List<Tuple<long, long>> chunks;
do
{

    HttpResult<List<Tuple<long, long>>> chunksResult;
    //get the chunks
    do
    {
        chunksResult = await RetrieveLargeUploadChunksAsync(uploadUrl, _10MB, length, ct);
        //TODO: should we delay on failure?
    } while (chunksResult.Value == null);//keep trying to get thre results until we're successful

    chunks = chunksResult.Value;

    //upload each fragment
    var chunkStream = new ChunkedReadStreamWrapper(data);
    foreach (var fragment in chunks)
    {
        //setup the chunked stream with the next fragment
        chunkStream.ChunkStart = fragment.Item1;

        //the size is one more than the difference (because the range is inclusive)
        chunkStream.ChunkSize = fragment.Item2 - fragment.Item1 + 1;

        //setup the headers for this request
        headers[0] = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Content-Length", chunkStream.ChunkSize.ToString());
        headers[1] = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Content-Range", $"bytes {fragment.Item1}-{fragment.Item2}/{length}");

        //submit the request until it is successful
        do
        {
            //this should not be authenticated
            response = await _httpClient.StartRequest(uploadUrl, HttpMethod.Put)
                .SetContent(chunkStream)
                .SetContentHeaders(headers)
                .SendAsync(ct);

        } while (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode); // keep retrying until success
    }

    //parse the response to see if there are more chunks or the final metadata
    responseJObject = await HttpClientHelper.ReadResponseAsJObjectAsync(response);

    //try to get chunks from the response to see if we need to retry anything
    chunks = ParseLargeUploadChunks(responseJObject, _10MB, length);
}
while (chunks.Count > 0);//keep going until no chunks left
```

Everything does what the comments say or what the name suggests, but a lot of the methods/classes are my own, so i'd be happy to explain anything that might not be obvious.

I have absolutely no idea what's going on and would appreciate any help.  I'm trying to get this done before I go back to school on Saturday and no longer have time to work on it.

**EDIT:**  After waiting a while, requests can be made to the upload URL again via PostMan.

**EDIT 2:** I can no longer replicate this timeout phenomenon in Postman.  Whether I get the upload URL from my application, or from another Postman request, and whether or not the upload has stalled in my application, I can seem to upload all the fragments I want to through Postman.

**EDIT 3:** This not-responding behavior starts before the content stream is read from.

**Edit 4:** Looking at packet info on WireShark, the first two chunks are almost identical, but only "resend" packets show up on the third.

Answer (score 0):

So after 3 weeks of varying levels of testing, I have finally figured out the issue and it has almost nothing to do with the OneDrive `Graph` api.  The issue was that when making the Http requests, I was using the `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` but not reading the responses before sending the next one.  This means that the `HttpClient` was preventing me from sending more requests until I read the responses from the old ones.  It was strange because it allowed me to send 2 requests before locking up.